# hibernate lowercase column names

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to insert row into database. But Hibernate changes column name to lowercase when inserting. It gives error *Invalid colum name 'monitoring'*

```
Hibernate: insert into dbo.Client(monitoring, AK) values (?,?)


private Boolean monitoring;

@Basic
@javax.persistence.Column(name = "Monitoring")


public Boolean isMonitoring() {
    return monitoring;
}

public void setMonitoring(Boolean monitoring) {
    this.monitoring = monitoring;
}

private String ak;

@Basic
@javax.persistence.Column(name = "AK")
public String getAk() {
    return ak;
}

public void setAk(String ak) {
    this.ak = ak;
}
```

Comment: Please show the ddl of your table Client.

Comment: Can you please post your mapping of ID property?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'backquotes' within the annotation. For example:

```
@javax.persistence.Column(name = "`Monitoring`")
```

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-quotedidentifiers

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that Entity was generated and @Anotations where set on methods not on fields.

Comment: That might be true for your "AK" column, but your "Monitoring" column (which was the one your were questioning) is against a field. Are you now saying that works as you have listed it in the question?

Comment: No I reedited for question and made typo. Fixed question now to reflect what problem was in the beginning. Sincerely thank you for time spent reading and trying to solve it.

Comment: Seriously? Did you not copy and paste the code into the question? That kind of typo wastes valuable time.